# Jquery: if class exists in element hide element

Tags: jquery, hide

```
if( ('.container').closest('.item7') = true){

     hide THE container of item7.

     //----
     //need help with this line
     //something like $closest('.item7').('.container').hide();
     //----

}
```

Summary:

if item7 class exists in container hide THE container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.item7').each(function() {
    $(this).parents('.container').hide();
});
```

Here's a Fiddle, showing it working > http://jsfiddle.net/ULZGH/

Comment: @Henrico its isnt the right answer.... it is very wasteful... all the item7 will be scanned in the document event if theres no container...

Answer (score 1):

**simple :**

```
   $('.container').each (function () {

if ($(this).has('.item7').length>0 ){

      $(this).hide();

    }

})
```

Comment: The statement `if( $('.container').has('.item7')` is always true (because it returns a jQuery object which always evalautes to true) so this just hides all `.container` objects.

Comment: This will hide all with class `container` if one contain the class `item7`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have more containers, you should loop them :)

```
$('.container').each( function() {
  if( $(this).find('.item7').length ){
        $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: you dont have to do each in this case

Comment: This looks for `.item7` objects which are parents of the `.container` object.  I don't think that's what the question is asking for.  Also, the statement `if( $(this).closest('.item7') )` is always true because it evaluates to a jQuery object.

Comment: If you go up and down the DOM its much better to do an each, in my opinion, so you either don't have to make more DOM calls, or overuse parent/children/find :)

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry didn't consider the code he provided. You are indeed right.. updated.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but after reading your question multiple times, my guess is that you want logic like this.  If the `.container` object has an object in it anywhere with the `.item7` class, then hide the `.container` parent object.  If that's what you're really trying to do, you can do it like this:

```
$('.container .item7').closest('.container').hide();
```

This will find any `.item7` objects that are in a `.container` and then hide the closest `.container` parent object of each match.

If there's a `.container` that does not contain a `.item7`, it will not be touched.  If there's a `.item7` that is not in a `.container`, it will not be touched.

If there could be multiple levels of containers and you wanted to hide them all, you could do it like this:

```
$('.container .item7').parents('.container').hide();
```

This finds all `.item7` object and then hides any `.container` parents.

My preferred way of doing it is actually this.  This would be more efficient if there were only a few `.container` objects, but lots of `.item7` objects:

```
$('.container').has('item7').hide();
```

This says to find each `.container` object.  Then in that resulting jQuery object (of all `.container` objects), remove any `.container` object that don't have a descendant `.item7` and then hide the reminaing `.container` objects.